# JIRA REST CLIENT: can't send attachments

Tags: java, maven, jira, jira-rest-java-api, jira-rest-api

**Problem:** exception (see stacktrace below) on sending attachments to jira via jira rest client

**Important!**

1. It works well when to start application on localhost via Jira.
2. It doesn't work on environment OR if to make a jar via `mvn clean package` command and launch via 'java -jar .jar' command!

**Question:** What is the reason? What should I try?

**Code:**

```
public static void handleProfileAttachments(Profile profile, JiraRestClient restClient, BasicIssue issue, ProgressMonitor pm) {
    List<FileInfo> attachments = profile.getFiles();
    if (attachments != null && !attachments.isEmpty()) {
        addAttachmentToIssue(restClient, issue.getKey(), attachments, pm);
    }
}

private static void addAttachmentToIssue(JiraRestClient restClient, String issueKey, List<FileInfo> attachments, ProgressMonitor pm) {
    FileInfo attachment = attachments.get(attachments.size() - 1);
    restClient.getIssueClient().addAttachment(pm, getIssue(restClient, issueKey, pm).getAttachmentsUri(),
            new ByteArrayInputStream(attachment.getFileContent().getContent()), attachment.getFileName() + "." + attachment.getFileExtension());
}
```

**Dependencies:**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.1-m02</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Stacktrace**

```
com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.RestClientException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java class com.sun.jersey.multipart.MultiPart, and Java type class com.sun.jersey.multipart.MultiPart, and MIME media type multipart/f
orm-data; boundary=Boundary_2_61827_1394804460392 was not found
        at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient.invoke(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:75)
        at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.JerseyIssueRestClient.addAttachments(JerseyIssueRestClient.java:345)
        at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.JerseyIssueRestClient.addAttachment(JerseyIssueRestClient.java:338)
        at com.levi9.levirs.jiraexport.JiraExportService.addAttachmentToIssue(JiraExportService.java:140)
        at com.levi9.levirs.jiraexport.JiraExportService.handleProfileAttachments(JiraExportService.java:227)
        at com.levi9.levirs.jiraexport.JiraExportService.updateIssueAttachment(JiraExportService.java:221)
        at com.levi9.levirs.communication.file.FileRequestHandler$Update.saveSession(FileRequestHandler.java:112)
        at com.levi9.levirs.communication.file.FileRequestHandler$Update.handle(FileRequestHandler.java:88)
        at com.levi9.levirs.core.Peer.onWebSocketText(Peer.java:33)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.ListenerEventDriver.onTextMessage(ListenerEventDriver.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.message.SimpleTextMessage.messageComplete(SimpleTextMessage.java:69)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.ListenerEventDriver.onTextFrame(ListenerEventDriver.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.EventDriver.incomingFrame(EventDriver.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketSession.incomingFrame(WebSocketSession.java:309)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.extensions.ExtensionStack.incomingFrame(ExtensionStack.java:203)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.Parser.notifyFrame(Parser.java:200)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.Parser.parse(Parser.java:237)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.read(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:551)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillable(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:459)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:596)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:527)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java class com.sun.jersey.multipart.MultiPart, and Java type class com.sun.jersey.multipart.MultiPart, and MIME media type multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary_2_61827_13948
04460392 was not found
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter$RequestEntityWriterImpl.<init>(RequestWriter.java:198)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter.getRequestEntityWriter(RequestWriter.java:259)
        at com.sun.jersey.client.apache.DefaultApacheHttpMethodExecutor.executeMethod(DefaultApacheHttpMethodExecutor.java:121)
        at com.sun.jersey.client.apache.ApacheHttpClientHandler.handle(ApacheHttpClientHandler.java:175)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:629)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.voidHandle(WebResource.java:625)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$400(WebResource.java:74)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:495)
        at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.JerseyIssueRestClient.postFileMultiPart(JerseyIssueRestClient.java:413)
        at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.JerseyIssueRestClient.access$300(JerseyIssueRestClient.java:85)
        at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.JerseyIssueRestClient$9.call(JerseyIssueRestClient.java:359)
        at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.JerseyIssueRestClient$9.call(JerseyIssueRestClient.java:345)
        at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.AbstractJerseyRestClient.invoke(AbstractJerseyRestClient.java:54)
        ... 22 more
```

Comment: Would you share the code you have written to communicate with Jira?

Comment: @cheffe look at updated question, please

Comment: @V_B did you get solution for this? me too facing the same problem

Comment: @eatSleepCode sorry that was far ago, I don't remember